# What is the differences in these declarations?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am learning about uses of data structures and came across some doubts:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}*head;
```

Question1: In the above structure, what does declaring a **struct node *next** within the structure mean?. And how is it different from simply declaring a pointer variable within structure as **int *next**

Question2: We can see that, at the end of the structure definition, a pointer ***head** is declared of type node and is used to access the structure members if I am right. Is this same as declaring it like this:

```
                            struct node *head;
```

Any help with this would be great. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very commonly how Linked Lists are declared in C. Recall — a linked list is a series of nodes which contain data as well as a *link* (in this case, a pointer) to the next node in the series.

So, each object of type `struct node` should contain a pointer to another `struct node`. This is characterized by declaring a field `next` in the struct with type `struct node *`.

As for your second question: the code you provided both defines `struct node` (allowing you to instantiate objects of type `struct node`), and declares a pointer to such a struct called `head`. You could certainly define the variable `head` the way you asked, but you would still need to define the struct somewhere earlier in the code. This is usually done in a separate header file, but could be done in the same `.c` source code file for brevity.

Now, note that both these methods will not actually create a `struct node` object. All you're doing is declaring a pointer to one. The object doesn't yet exist anywhere since you never allocated space for it. To do that, you'd need to use `malloc`:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} * head;

head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You could also declare a runtime stack instance of the struct, which just means you won't need to explicitly free the memory you allocated with `malloc()`. The memory allocated for the struct is deallocated when you return from the function, or when your program terminates if declared outside of any functions.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer with clear description :)

Answer (score 1):

"struct node *next" declares a variable called next which points to a "struct node". In other words, a singly linked list.

You are correct in that the statement does two things:

1. Declares a struct called node (with an int called data and a
   pointer to the next struct node)
2. Declares a variable called head pointing to the struct node.

These could have been done separately as follows:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `next` as `struct node *next` means that it points to a `struct node`, presumably the next node in the list.  If it were instead declared as `int *next` then it would point to an `int`, which it doesn't seem there's any need for.

The answer to question 2 is yes.  They are simply combining the definition of `struct node` with the declaration of `head`.  They could be split apart as you indicated.